# Finding no.of decimals from a particular column

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have one table in which I want to find no.of decimal places in a particular column, I just want to get records which have more then 2 decimal places

I am trying this:

```
SELECT amount    
FROM fin_payment_scheduledetail where amount ilike '%._____'
```

ERROR:

> operator does not exist: numeric ~~* unknown

Answer (score 0):

from you error I see numeric data type, and thus example:

```
t=# with f(l) as (values(3.092::numeric),(0),(0.2),(9.000))
select l,position('.' in l::text),char_length(l::text), char_length(l::text)-position('.' in l::text) dug2more from f;
   l   | position | char_length | dug2more
-------+----------+-------------+----------
 3.092 |        2 |           5 |        3
     0 |        0 |           1 |        1
   0.2 |        2 |           3 |        1
 9.000 |        2 |           5 |        3
(4 rows)
```

`9.000` is considered as having 3 digits after dot, which mathematically would be wrong (cos its not three - its zero, or three or forty two - all which are not equal alltogether, thus saying it is three is nonsence)

thus for the sake of arythmetics I'd add one more explicit cast:

```
t=# with f(l) as (values(3.092::numeric::float),(0),(0.2),(9.000))
select l,position('.' in l::text),char_length(l::text), char_length(l::text)-position('.' in l::text) dug2more
from f;
   l   | position | char_length | dug2more
-------+----------+-------------+----------
 3.092 |        2 |           5 |        3
     0 |        0 |           1 |        1
   0.2 |        2 |           3 |        1
     9 |        0 |           1 |        1
(4 rows)
```

and lastly regarding using regexp:

```
t=# with f(l) as (values(3.092::numeric),(0),(0.2),(9.000))
select l,l::text ~ '\d{1,}.\d{2,}' from f;
   l   | ?column?
-------+----------
 3.092 | t
     0 | f
   0.2 | f
 9.000 | t
(4 rows)
```

as you can see comparison is true in case of 9.000. So its up to you what you want here - semantic check of arithmetic one